# Style attribute removed when trying to save image url to database using summernote Editor

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, summernote

I am using Summernote editor to save text and images to db.Currently i have embedded summernote in Codeigniter so i am uploading image file to server and then retrieve back the url and insert the image into the editor. Now according to documentation we can resize image uploaded to server and can apply the css to image.

Code for Insertion And applying Css which shows the Perfect result.Note  data-filename attribute is saving .

```
 $('#summernote').summernote('insertImage', objFile, function ($image) {
                        $image.css('width', $image.width() / 3);
                        $image.attr('data-filename', 'retriever');
                    });
```

Everything is fine except when i submit form the style attribute get removed from the img tag and the rest of the data get saved.

My Controller Function Where i am saving data to db.

```
if($this->input->post())
        {
            var_dump($_POST);
            $this->data=array(
            'PageID'=>$this->input->post('PageID'),
            'Title'=>$this->input->post('Title'),
            'Description'=>$this->input->post('Description'),
            'Text'=>$this->input->post('Text'),
            'CreatedBy' => 1,
            'CreatedDate' => date('Y-m-d'),
            'UpdatedBy' => 1,
            'IsActive' => 1,
            'IsDeleted' => 0
            );

            $Where=array('PageID'=>$this->input->post('PageID'));
            $Result=$this->model->insert('pagedata',$this->data,'ID',$this->input->post('PageID'),$Where);
            if($Result)
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('Success',"Page Updated Successfully");
                $Path=previousURL();
                redirect($Path);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('Error',"Sorry Couldnt Update The Page");
                $Path=previousURL();
                redirect($Path);
            }
        }
```

Note in var_dump i see that the style attribute applied to the img but when data reach to db the style attribute isnt there My problem is that `style` tag is not saving up in db while it apply to images when i upload them i meant to say it exists

Answer (score 3):

The problem you are facing is caused by CodeIgniter's XSS filtering which removes or strips the style attribute from the image string, and then passes the data to the database.

Change:

```
$this->input->post('TextAreaName')
```

To

```
$_POST['TextAreaName']
```